# Pattern for generic unit test of type class instance implementations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hunit

I was wondering if there was a known pattern for writing generic unit test code whose purpose it is to check (as a black box) the various instance (implementation of) a type class. For example:

```
import Test.HUnit

class M a where
foo :: a -> String
cons :: Int -> a     -- some constructor

data A = A Int
data B = B Int

instance M A where
  foo _ = "foo"
  cons  = A

instance M B where
  foo _ = "bar"     -- implementation error
  cons  = B
```

I would like to write a function `tests` returning a `Test` with some way of specifying to `tests` the particular instance to which the code applies. I was thinking adding `tests`to the definition of the class with a default implementation (ignoring the coupling issue between testing code and actual code for now), but I can't simply have `tests :: Test`, and even if I try `tests:: a -> Test` (so having to artificially pass a concrete element of the given type to call the function), I cannot figure out how to refer to `cons` and `foo` inside the code (type annotations like `(cons 0) :: a` won't do).

Assuming I have `class (Eq a) => M a where ...` instead, with types `A` and `B` deriving `Eq`, I could trick the compiler with something like (added to the definition of `M`):

```
tests :: a -> Test
tests x = let 
            y = (cons 0)
            z = (x == y)       -- compiler now knows y :: a
          in
            TestCase (assertEqual "foo" (foo y)  "foo")

main = do
  runTestTT $ TestList
   [ tests (A 0)
   , tests (B 0)
   ]
```

But this is all very ugly to me. Any suggestion is warmly welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Proxy

The current most common way of making a function polymorphic in an "internal" type is to pass a `Proxy`. `Proxy` has a single nullary constructor like `()`, but its type carries a phantom type. This avoids having to pass `undefined` or dummy values. `Data.Proxy.asProxyTypeOf` can then be used as an annotation.

```
tests :: M a => Proxy a -> Test
tests a = TestCase (assertEqual "foo" (foo (cons 0 `asProxyTypeOf` a)) "foo")
```

### proxy

We can also generalize that type, as the `Proxy` is not actually being needed as a value. It's just a way of making a type variable non-ambiguous. You need to redefine `asProxyTypeOf` though. This is mostly a matter of style compared to the previous one. Being able to use more values as potential proxies can make some code more concise, sometimes at the cost of readability.

```
-- proxy is a type variable of kind * -> *
tests :: M a => proxy a -> Test
tests a = TestCase (assertEqual "foo" (foo (cons 0 `asProxyTypeOf` a)) "foo")
  where
    asProxyTypeOf :: a -> proxy a -> a
    asProxyTypeOf = const
```

### Scoped type variables

The function `asProxyTypeOf`, or your `(==)` trick are really a product of the inability to refer to a type variable from a signature. This is in fact allowed by the `ScopedTypeVariables`+`RankNTypes` extensions.

Explicit quantification brings the variable `a` into scope in the body of the function.

```
tests :: forall a proxy. M a => proxy a -> Test
tests _ = TestCase (assertEqual "foo" (foo (cons 0 :: a)) "foo")  -- the "a" bound by the top-level signature.
```

Without the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, `cons 0 :: a` would be interpreted as `cons 0 :: forall a. a` instead.

Here's how you use these functions:

```
main = runTestTT $ TestList
  [ tests (Proxy :: Proxy A)
  , tests (Proxy :: Proxy B)
  ]
```

### Type applications

Since GHC 8, the `AllowAmbiguousTypes`+`TypeApplications` extensions make the `Proxy` argument unnecessary.

```
tests :: forall a. M a => Test
tests = TestCase (assertEqual "foo" (foo (cons 0 :: a)) "foo")  -- the "a" bound by the top-level signature.

main = runTestTT $ TestList
  [ tests @A
  , tests @B
  ]
```

Comment: This is great thank you!! Will try all these suggestions carefully as I expect to learn a lot from the exercise.